# Show more inputs based on select in PHP Foreach Loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach

I have a PHP Foreach loop that contains a "Quantity" input. Users can select a quantity and then that quantity selected should display the selected # of new inputs. If I choose a quantity of "3" then 3 new inputs should appear for that item. Remember, I have a forreach loop so I have multiple items.

As of right now, my code only works to display the new number of inputs for the FIRST item only. I need it to work for every item in the forreach loop. See my code below:

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
                 $appareltype = $row['appareltype'];
                    $apparel = explode(",", $appareltype);
                    foreach($apparel as $datapparel) {
                        ?>
                            <b><? echo $datapparel ?></b><br>
                            Quantity: <select name="quantity[]" class="form-control quantity">
                            <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="11">11</option>
                            <option value="12">12</option>
                            <option value="13">13</option>
                            <option value="14">14</option>
                            <option value="15">15</option>
                            <option value="16">16</option>
                            <option value="17">17</option>
                            <option value="18">18</option>
                            <option value="19">19</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>

                            <div id="text">

                            </div>

                        <?
                    }

            }
                     ?>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("select.quantity").change(function () {
  var str = "";
  var count = Number($("select option:selected").val())
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      str += '<div class="oneinput"> <label>' + i
              + "</label> <input name='" + i + "' class='form-control'>"
              + "</div>";
  }

  $("#text").html(str);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.  First, in your jQuery, use

```
$(this).find("option:selected").val()
```

instead of

```
$("select option:selected").val()
```

Second, you're creating multiple `div` elements with the same ID ('text'). You can only have an ID once in the DOM. Get rid of the ID on that element. Maybe replace it with some identifiable class if you want.

So how to inject the new content into the divs now? Use `$(this).next().html(str);`

Finally, close your `select` element before the `div`.

```
…
    <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
<div class="something"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to close the `</select>`.  Then don't use an `ID` selector the text as it should only be referenced once.  Finally use `$(this)` to make your jQuery relative.

```
<?php
$rows = array(array('appareltype'=>'hat,gloves,earmuffs,socks,jumper'));
foreach($rows as $row) {
                 $appareltype = $row['appareltype'];
             echo $appareltype;
                   $apparel = explode(",", $appareltype);
                print_r($apparel);
                foreach($apparel as $datapparel) {
                    ?>
                        <b><? echo $datapparel ?></b><br>
                        Quantity: <select name="quantity[]" class="form-control quantity">
                        <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
  <div class="text">

</div>

                    <?
                }

        }
                 ?>
                     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
                     <script type="text/javascript">
$("select.quantity").change(function () {
  var str = "";
  //var count = Number($(this).("select option:selected").val())
  var count = Number($(this).val());
  for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
      str += '<div class="oneinput"> <label>' + i
              + "</label> <input name='" + i + "' class='form-control'>"
              + "</div>";
  }

  $(this).next(".text").html(str);
});
</script>
```

Comment: @mustbebuilt How is this not exactly what I said?

Comment: @PatrickQ - yep very similar but I used slightly different jQuery.